# Looping through promise and waiting?

Tags: javascript, loops, express, asynchronous, async-await

I made a function that connects to an API which returns an array with 100 objects at a time. Without the loop the getPageData() function works when you pass an int. However when I try to iterate through it, it gives me back nothing. Set timeout function doesn't seem to help the loop.

Please help

```
async function updateWholeDB(){
    var results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < getPages(); i++) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            getPageData(i).then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                results.push(data) ;
            })
        }, 2000)

        }
    return Promise.all(results);
}
```

Comment: Promise.all outside a promise? Also what are you expecting setTimeout to do?

Comment: `Promise.all()` does it's work properly when you pass it an array of promises, not an array of results.  It then returns a promise that resolves to an array of results.  So, you're not using it properly.

Comment: ```getPageData()``` returns a promise. The data ```getPageData()```returns is pushed the results array. The ```Promise.all()``` checks to make sure the results array have resolved promises. The set timeout was meant to give the promise time to resolve

Comment: @Amissi `setTimeout()` doesn't block execution, all it accomplishes in your code is to delay each call to `getPageData()`. Your function return `return Promise.all(results)` will happen before any of the timeouts or promises have resolved and `results` is still an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` does it's work properly when you pass it an array of promises, not an array of results. It then returns a promise that resolves to an array of results. So, you're not using it properly.

In addition, there doesn't appear to be any reason for a `setTimeout()` here if things are coded properly.

If what you're trying to do is to end up with an array of results from calling `getPageData()` a bunch of times, you can do that like this:

```
function updateWholeDB(){
    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < getPages(); i++) { 
        promises.push(getPageData(i));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

// usage
updateWholeDB().then(results => {
   console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

This assumes that `getPageData()` returns a promise that resolves properly with the data you are interested in.  If that's not the case, then you will have to show us that code too so we can offer advice on how to fix it.